# Image editing using ImageMagick PHP library

Tags: php, imagemagick

I am developing image editor, i successfully write text on images on position x,y, now i need to draw a white image on image that is called white out. white image will be drawn at position cord X, cord Y and dynamic size of image  width, height. i write code but i am not getting the image on right coordinates and height width of image.
here is my image rendering function.

[image]

```
 $image = new Imagick('image.jpg');

    $diagnose=$this->input->post('diagnoses');  
    $fontsize=$this->input->post('fontsize');
    $fontstyle=$this->input->post('fontstyle');

        $cordX   = $this->input->post('posX'); 
        $cordY   = $this->input->post('posY');

        $font_size = 20;
        // Watermark text
        //$diagnose = "Hello world.{newline}It's a beautiful day.";


        $textlinesArray = explode("{newline}",$diagnose);

        // Create a new drawing palette
        $draw = new ImagickDraw();

        // Set font properties
        $draw->setFont('Arial');
        $draw->setFontSize($font_size);
        $draw->setFillColor('black');

        // Position text at the bottom-right of the image
        $draw->setGravity(Imagick::GRAVITY_NORTHWEST);

        $i = 0;
        foreach ($textlinesArray as $index => $text) {   
             $newY = ($i * $font_size)  + $cordY;
             //echo $newY . "</br>";
             //echo $text;
             // Draw text on the image
             $image->annotateImage($draw,  $cordX, $newY,0, $text);
             $i++;

        }

        $draw->setFillColor('magenta');    // Set up some colors to use for fill and outline
        $draw->setStrokeColor( new ImagickPixel( 'cyan' ) );
        $draw->setStrokeWidth(2);
        $draw->rectangle($cordX, $cordY, 200, 300);    // Draw the rectangle 

        $image->drawImage( $draw );

        // Set output image format
        $image->setImageFormat('png');

        // Output the new image
        header('Content-type: image/png');
        echo $image;
```

here is the output, i need that color box dynamic width height and position